# Python and jump to definition

Tags: cloud9-ide

How to set jump to definition correctly for python projects on Cloud9? Any documentation for this? For me it only works when I open a file with that definition, in other way this option is inactive.

[image: Cloud9 - Jump to Definition]

In case if this is important: I created a virtualenv in /home/ubuntu/workspace/MYVENV and python project is in /home/ubuntu/workspace/MYVENV/project/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Right now, Jump to Definition is only available for functions in the same file. I'll add a feature request for multi-file definition jumping.